# Send all fields from a table row in a table wrapped in a form - Angular

Tags: angular

I have an Angular table in Angular and Currently I am sending the id_number on submit, but what I want to do is send all the data from a table row? my code so far is:

**html file**

```
 <form [formGroup]="assetForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
     <table class="table table-striped table-hover mb-10">
         <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Number</th>
              <th>Sev</th>
              <th>Phone</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
             <tr *ngFor="let incident of data">
               <td>
                  <label class="form-radio">
                      <input type="radio" name="id_number" [value]="incident.number" formControlName="id_number" />
                    <i class="form-icon"></i>{{incident.number}}
                  </label></td>
                <td>{{incident.sev}}</td>
                <td>{{incident.phone}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
       </table>
       <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!Form.valid" type="submit">Select</button>
  </form>
```

**Ts.file**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.assetForm = new FormGroup({
      id_number: new FormControl(''),
    });
  }

onSubmit() {
    if (this.assetForm.invalid) {
      this.assetForm.setErrors({ ...this.assetForm.errors, 'required': true });
      return;
    }
    this.uploading = true;
    this.service.post(this.assetForm.value).subscribe((response: any) => {
      console.log(response);//On success response

    }, (errorResponse: any) => {
      console.log(errorResponse); //On unsuccessful response
      this.error = true;
      this.uploading = false;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You has two options

**Option one**

```
<input type="radio" name="id_number" [ngValue]="incident" formControlName="id_number" >
```

Yes, using ng_Value, make the value of the FormControl was the whole object. The problem is if you want to initialize the form with a concrete value

**Option two**
In submit find the object from the list and seng the object

```
onSubmit() {
    if (this.assetForm.invalid) {
      this.assetForm.setErrors({ ...this.assetForm.errors, 'required': true });
      return;
    }
    this.uploading = true;
    //find the object
    let data=this.data.find(x=>x.number==this.assetForm.value)
    //and send it
    this.service.post(data).subscribe((response: any) => {
      console.log(response);//On success response

    }, (errorResponse: any) => {
      console.log(errorResponse); //On unsuccessful response
      this.error = true;
      this.uploading = false;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In component in `onSubmit()` before post data to service need to find selected incident. Something just like this:

```
const selectedIncident = this.data
 .find((incident) => incident.number === this.assetForm.get('id_number').value);
```

And then send it to service:

```
this.service.post(selectedIncident).subscribe((response: any) => {
      console.log(response);//On success response

    }, (errorResponse: any) => {
      console.log(errorResponse); //On unsuccessful response
      this.error = true;
      this.uploading = false;
    });
```

Hope I helped you :)